# I need help deciphering this javascript

Tags: javascript, comments, cdata

In the beginning of a block of HTML, I found this:

```
<body><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript1.2">//<![CDATA[
<!--
     ...a bunch of if/thens that drive a browser specific line of text...
//-->
//]]></script>
```

I'm confused because I would expect the HTML and javascript comment tags `<!--`  `-->` and `//` to prevent the code from running, in essence parsing to

`<body><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript1.2"></script>`

However, I'm getting the browser-specific text displaying and there doesn't seem to be anyplace else that it's being generated. Does the `<![CDATA[` somehow override the javascript comment, allowing the script to run, while the HTML comments inside the `CDATA` block are preventing the javascript from displaying in the browser? Can someone help me understand how this all gets parsed and displayed/used?

Comment: [Script and Style elements in XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8)

Comment: [What does CDATA in XML mean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784294/1142380)

Answer (score 1):

`<!-- -->` is only used for HTML comments, not for javascript comments. Javascript uses `//` for single-line and `/* */` for multi line comments. If you do use `<!-- -->` in javascript it would normally just be ignored. Some browsers may throw a javascript error on it.

Answer (score 1):

First, all JS code is put here inside CDATA section (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Use_of_CDATA_in_program_output)). That's why there are comments `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>`.
That allows to write arbitary characters inside JS code, including characters, which are considered as special symbols for XML, like '<', '>', etc.

HTML comment start `<!--` denotes a start for single comment in JavaScript (see [this article](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/comments.htm)). HTML comment end - `-->` has no meaning in JavaScript, that's why it is preceded by `//`.
HTML comments are used here to hide JavaScript code from browsers, which do not support JavaScript. For that browsers, the code will be just a text between `<!--` and `-->` and will not be displayed on a page.
Commenting in a such way is a very old practice.

In any case, the best is to have all JavaScript code in a separate file and to include that file using `<script>` tag. That way one will avoid using both CDATA and HTML comments.